# Change package name doesn't make changes in generated file

Tags: android, gradle, package

My package name was `com.softmills.ogram` and i have changed to `com.ogram.sp` and change applicationId in gradle file as well and clean the project and invalidate cash and restart it showed that error

```
D:\ogram\app\build\generated\source\navigation-args\debug\com\ogram\sp\ui\cancel\CancelFragmentArgs.java:8: error: package com.softmills.ogram.common.model does not exist
```

import com.softmills.ogram.common.model.Shift;

and here is android generated class

```
package com.ogram.sp.ui.cancel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.navigation.NavArgs;
import com.softmills.ogram.common.model.Shift;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.SuppressWarnings;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CancelFragmentArgs implements NavArgs {
  private final HashMap arguments = new HashMap();

  private CancelFragmentArgs() {
  }

  private CancelFragmentArgs(HashMap argumentsMap) {
    this.arguments.putAll(argumentsMap);
  }

  @NonNull
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static CancelFragmentArgs fromBundle(@NonNull Bundle bundle) {
    CancelFragmentArgs __result = new CancelFragmentArgs();
    bundle.setClassLoader(CancelFragmentArgs.class.getClassLoader());
    if (bundle.containsKey("shifts")) {
      Shift[] shifts;
      Parcelable[] __array = bundle.getParcelableArray("shifts");
      if (__array != null) {
        shifts = new Shift[__array.length];
        System.arraycopy(__array, 0, shifts, 0, __array.length);
      } else {
        shifts = null;
      }
      __result.arguments.put("shifts", shifts);
    }
    return __result;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Nullable
  public Shift[] getShifts() {
    return (Shift[]) arguments.get("shifts");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @NonNull
  public Bundle toBundle() {
    Bundle __result = new Bundle();
    if (arguments.containsKey("shifts")) {
      Shift[] shifts = (Shift[]) arguments.get("shifts");
      __result.putParcelableArray("shifts", shifts);
    }
    return __result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) {
        return true;
    }
    if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    CancelFragmentArgs that = (CancelFragmentArgs) object;
    if (arguments.containsKey("shifts") != that.arguments.containsKey("shifts")) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getShifts() != null ? !getShifts().equals(that.getShifts()) : that.getShifts() != null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = 1;
    result = 31 * result + java.util.Arrays.hashCode(getShifts());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "CancelFragmentArgs{"
        + "shifts=" + getShifts()
        + "}";
  }

  public static class Builder {
    private final HashMap arguments = new HashMap();

    public Builder(CancelFragmentArgs original) {
      this.arguments.putAll(original.arguments);
    }

    public Builder() {
    }

    @NonNull
    public CancelFragmentArgs build() {
      CancelFragmentArgs result = new CancelFragmentArgs(arguments);
      return result;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Builder setShifts(@Nullable Shift[] shifts) {
      this.arguments.put("shifts", shifts);
      return this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Nullable
    public Shift[] getShifts() {
      return (Shift[]) arguments.get("shifts");
    }
  }
}
```

this line that caused the problem `import com.softmills.ogram.common.model.Shift;`
i don't know why it still see the old package name so i change it manually and rerun again but the same issue cause it's generated class

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: yes, just change the args from navigation file itself
and please mark upvote my question